# How can I generate a link with a variable? Using javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables, hyperlink

I tried to create a function which generates a link and added it to an element. But the .click function wont work. I dont even get an error, thats why I'm not sure if the function or the variable is wrong.

This is my javascript code:

```
 $("#nwa1").click(function(){

   var titel = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
       
           link = '';
           link += 'nwa_' + titel + '.json'
       
        $.getJSON(link, function(json){
            aus = '';
            aus += '<table border="1"><tr><th>Kcal</th><th>Eiweiß in g</th><th>Fett in g</th></tr>';
            for (i = 0; i < json.werte.length; i++){
                aus += '<td>' + json.werte[i].kcal + '</td>' + '<td>' + json.werte[i].eiweiß + '</td>' + '<td>' + json.werte[i].fett + '</td>';
            }
            aus += '</tr></table>';
            $('#div2').html(aus);
        })
   })
```

And here is the html page:

```
 <h4 id="nwa1">Nährwertangaben</h4>
            <div id="div2" ></div>
```

The link i want to open with the function is nwa_falafel.json and 'falafel' is my h1-element.

Thank you, for trying to help!:)

Comment: If you're not getting an error from the code, check the network tab of the console to see exactly what the response is from the AJAX call. You'll need to debug it. Also note that your HTML is missing the opening `<tr>` within the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is the element h1? Does that exist somewhere else?

I made a jsfiddle to see if that would help in some way. I was getting an error on the h1 element not being there so perhaps that would be a start? What does your json file look like?

https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/g4e9bd0q/20/

Comment: The h1 element is in the same htlm file as the h4 element `<h1 id="h1">Falafel</h1>`. And the variable title works in an other function:  `function myFav() { var titel = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
        if (localStorage.getItem(titel) == null){
           localStorage.setItem(titel, dn);  
            }else { localStorage.removeItem(titel, dn); } `

Comment: This is the .json file `{ 
"werte":[

 {"kcal": "637",
 "eiweiß": "17.75",
    "fett": "44.93" }
]
} `

Comment: Check the console network tab.  Check that the url from getJSON is what you expect.  See if you get a response or 404.  Noone else can do this for you.

Comment: Try this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/g4e9bd0q/32/
that is at least populating the html so that part works.
It might be that the path to your json file needs to be checked. (what James said!)

Comment: With the console network tab i get the status: 304 Not modified.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the path to your JSON file. Try the (working) code below and check the console for to see if it is logging an error.

```
      $("#nwa1").click(function()
      {
          alert('genau!');
          $titel = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
          $link = '';
          $link += 'nwa_' + $titel + '.json'

          $.getJSON( $link, {
            format: "json"
          })
            .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
          })
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log("done");
                console.log(data.werte);
                aus = '';
                aus += '<table border="1"><tr><th>Kcal</th><th>Eiweiß in g</th><th>Fett in g</th></tr>';
                $.each( data.werte, function( i, item ) {
                    aus += '<td>' + item.kcal + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.eiweiß + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.fett + '</td>';
                });
                aus += '</tr></table>';
                $('#div2').html(aus);
            });


      });
```

I added some colors my side just for emphasis:

[image]

So if you are getting an error check the location /path to your JSON file as the code works fine.